# Copying files in Windows 7 command line - The System cannot find the file specified

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe

I know this is a stupid question I've made batch files for years and haven't had this much trouble... I'm trying to make a batch file to copy files into a folder and for the life of me I can't get it to work.

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Skyrim\Data\
copy FifthGenerationMage.bsa C:\Users\Mark Collins\Desktop\DATA
copy FifthGenerationMage.bsl C:\Users\Mark Collins\Desktop\DATA
copy FifthGenerationMage.ckm C:\Users\Mark Collins\Desktop\DATA
copy FifthGenerationMage.esp C:\Users\Mark Collins\Desktop\DATA
pause
```

This should work, right? Copy  , right? When I do it like this, it says the syntax is incorrect.

When I do this:

```
copy C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Skyrim\Data\FifthGenerationMage.bsa C:\Users\Mark Collins\Desktop\DATA
copy C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Skyrim\Data\FifthGenerationMage.bsl C:\Users\Mark Collins\Desktop\DATA
copy C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Skyrim\Data\FifthGenerationMage.ckm C:\Users\Mark Collins\Desktop\DATA
copy C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Skyrim\Data\FifthGenerationMage.esp C:\Users\Mark Collins\Desktop\DATA
```

It says "The System cannot find the file specified."

Both of those should work. I don't get it.

Comment: Where are the quotes since your paths contain spaces....Either that use the short hand for those folders.  Both of your commands are incorrect for that reason.

Comment: There is no DOS in Windows since Windows 2000. Windows XP and later Windows systems have text console, also called Command Line or CMD.

Comment: Ramhound of course. That was it. You rock. Kamil, I know, I know... it looks like DOS, so I call it DOS, even though it's not an operating system... While that is a very real distinction, I never understood why it was that important

Comment: @MarkCollins - Be specific.  If you know the difference use the correct term.  **The details are important.**  They are also the different between a quality question and something that isn't.

Comment: @MarkCollins Just want to inform that calling Windows console "DOS" is incorrect :)

Comment: It is worth noting that the `cd` command takes only one parameter (and a possible option), so the whole of the passed string is taken as the parameter (including blanks), which is why the quotes are optional. They _would_ be needed if the directory name has a leading or trailing blank.

Comment: mark, if you knew the correct terminology then you should have used it. Perhaps at the moment there isn't anybody more ignorant than you, but in let's say 5 years time, there may be some people reading your post, that are even more ignorant than you, and if you used the wrong terminology then they'll misunderstand things. Imagine if you read things people had written that didn't use the right terminology, you'd be even more ignorant than you are, and i'm sure you wouldn't want that, and certainly nobody else would want you to be any more ignorant. So don't knowingly use the wrong terminology.

Answer (score 10):

If your path contains spaces - you have to enclose whole path with `"`, like this:

```
copy "C:\Program Files (x86)\...\FifthGenerationMage.bsa" "C:\Users\...\DATA"
```

I would also suggest to use variable to store target path and simplify script:

```
set skyrimdata="C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Skyrim\Data"
set target="C:\Users\Mark Collins\Desktop\DATA"

copy "%skyrimdata%\FifthGenerationMage.bsa" %target%
copy "%skyrimdata%\FifthGenerationMage.bsl" %target%
copy "%skyrimdata%\FifthGenerationMage.ckm" %target%
copy "%skyrimdata%\FifthGenerationMage.esp" %target%
```

---

Why it doesnt work?

Look:

```
|     | 1         | 2    | 3               | 4      |5      |
 copy   C:\Folder   with   spaces\file.txt   E:\Some folder
```

System reads it as:

1 - parameter 1 (for copy command - source 1)

2 - parameter 2 (for copy command - source 2)

3 - parameter 3 (for copy command - source 3)

4 - parameter 4 (for copy command - source 4)

5 - parameter 5 (for copy command - target)

There are no `C:\Folder`, `with`, `spaces\file.txt` files or directories - and you get error:

> The System cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Adding some supplement information. This could also happen if one of the following characters are present in the filename `< > : " / \ | ?  *`. In my case, a script was extracting the forward slash instead of the date from the %date% variable and appending it to the filename. I kept getting the system cannot find the path error until I corrected the filename.